# Laravel set one object in relation to another multiple times

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many

I want that a component can contain one component multiple times. This is a many to many relationship.

```php
$component->contains()->sync($components);
```

Sync prevents multiple records. In other words I want that component with id 1 can be related to component 2 2 times.

```php
$component->contains
```

This should return component 2 2 times.

Is there a posibility to do this?

Comment: 2 times instead of 1?

Comment: Yes, or  3,4,... times.

Comment: Laravel can't model (as far as I know) a many to many relationship in which each pivot row is not unique for a pair of models. You might have to create a separate model for your pivot table and create a one-many and a many-on relationships between those models and the pivot model.

Comment: _The `sync()` method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the intermediate table_ - What you need is [`attach()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations) instead because you don't want to detach anything, right?

Comment: @senty yes this could be posible. But then I would have to detach manualy. I'll try it.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, using `sync` will override any existing componen that is already store, so if you had related components with ids: `1`, `3` and `5` and then use `sync()` to store components of ids: `2` and `5`, the total components stored will be: `2` and `5`. This is because the `sync` method will detach any relation that is not included as an argument.

From the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships):

> #### Syncing Associations
>
> You may also use the `sync` method to construct many-to-many
>   associations. The `sync` method accepts an array of IDs to place on
>   the intermediate table. **Any IDs that are not in the given array will**
>   **be removed from the intermediate table**. So, after this operation is
>   complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the
>   intermediate table:
>
> ```php
> $user->roles()->sync([1, 2, 3]);
> ```

To avoid this behavior try using `syncWithoutDetaching()`:

> If you do not want to detach existing IDs, you may use the
>   `syncWithoutDetaching` method:
>
> ```php
> $user->roles()->syncWithoutDetaching([1, 2, 3]);
> ```

Haven't test it, but this should be the expected behavior:

```php
$component = Component::find(1);
$component->contains->pluck('id');
// 1, 3, 5    
$component->contains()->syncWithoutDetaching([2, 3, 6]);
$component->contains->pluck('id');
// 1, 2, 3, 3, 6
```

---

You should notice that this `contains()` relationship match a collection method of the [same name](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-contains), be aware of this.

Comment: Yes, I thought about that too, but i need to detach. I could detach manualy but I thought there might be a better solution.